# How to combine jquery selector attributes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I combine some selectors in jquery to denie my function reacting on some fields ?

Sample:

My autocomplete aka. search function is called when any input field gets a values thats larger than 3 signs.

To exclude some inputs I use this

```
$('#customerdata input[name!="c_ldate"]').bind('keyup',function(){...
```

this works fine for one field. No I have a second input where my function not should react on.

I want to do something similar like

```
$('#customerdata input[name!="c_ldate"], input[name!="c_ldate2"]')...
```

but this doesnt work.

Is there an easy way to select an attribute (name) and say "if value is bla bla dont use this" short hand `name!="bla bla OR foo bar"`

Its difficult to add a fiddle... my fiddles dont work at all... even not when I use my working code... **wired**

Simply sayed:

I have 10 inputs inside a div and i want to exclude two of them by name!

**EDIT**

found my solution.

```
$('#customerdata input').not('[name!="c_ldate"]').not('[name!="c_ldate_text"]')
//or similar and bit shorter
$('#customerdata input').not('[name!="c_ldate"],[name!="c_ldate_text"]')
//shortest for me in my case
$('#customerdata input').not('[name^="c_ldate"]')
//what actually just checks if name attribte starts with... so this is fine for me as well
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder better ?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. I suggest adding a **runnable** [mcve] to the question with Stack Snippets, pointing out the fields you do and don't want handled, and how you can distinguish between them. I suspect [this](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) will be relevant.

Comment: ( _As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged._ )

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki thats nice to know but doesnt matters for me since this is an older project and updating jquery would call a lot of issures so sometimes you have to use the older version. Its also a very large code and cant be updated to easily :)

Comment: found my solution. `$('#customerdata input').not('[name!="c_ldate"]').not('[name!="c_ldate_text"]')` shorthand for me `$('#customerdata input').not('[name^="c_ldate"]')`

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to all inputs? Then 
    $(".class").bind...
If I understood your question correctly.

Comment: You can select things with names just fine, no need for classes.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, the comma operator between two CSS selectors is like a logical OR, but your selectors are working by exclusion.  Like this:  if( x!=3 || x !=4 ).  But that expression will not exclude any value of x.  I tried this with jQuery, in a form I happened to have handy:

```
   $("body").append("<div id='foo'><input name='fred'><input name='george'><input name='harry'>");
```

Then, the selectors:

```
$("#foo input[name!=fred]");
[input, input]
$("#foo input[name!=george]");
[input, input]
$("#foo input[name!=george], #foo input[name!=fred]");
[input, input, input]
```

So the last selector expression doesn't exclude any of the three inputs.

Comment: But as you can see in my post, im using this on all inputs inside a div. In my case #customrdata and i simply want to exclude 2 inputs by name

Comment: I fixed my example to more closely correspond to your question. Does that help?